# Call dynamicaly tel attribute when clicking button

Tags: jquery, html

I have a call button like this :

```
<a href="tel:01 01 01 01 01"></a>
```

But I would to turn it into :
`<a href="tel:"></a>` or other thing, and when I click on the a href, I pull phone number throught Ajax script and I trigger the call with this phone number.

How can I do this ?

Thank you

Comment: cant you just put the right number there?

Comment: after staring at your question for several minutes, i still have no idea what you mean.

Comment: Adding text to your anchor tag will create the link. 

'<a href="tel:01 01 01 01 01">01 01 01 01 01</a>'

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someting like this?

```
<a href="http://www.youtube.com" onclick="this.href = 'http://www.google.com'">Take me to the YouTube!</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an **iframe** that loads the "tel:" URL.

This solution works the same way how Android phones got hacked. Samsung had included special dial codes for wiping the phone. Manipulated websites just "called" something like *2767*3855# (this one wipes the Galaxy S3).

```js
function fetch_number() {
    // Do AJAX stuff here...
    return "123456789";
}

function call(number) {
    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');    
    iframe.style.display = "none";
    iframe.src = "tel:" + fetch_number();
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
}
```

```html
<a href="tel:123456789">Just call</a><br />
<a href="javascript:call();">Fetch number and call</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this simply way :

```
$.get('{{ "/www-ajax-get-number/id/1221", function( data ) {
   window.location = "tel:"+data;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

This sounds like its for mobile. Buuuut the way you have your href setup you would be getting random tel:'s. How would the user know what tel: they wanted?